# Shell command executed differently in a terminal and script

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, quoting, echo

The following sequence of commands

```
ch=`echo "b_d" | sed 's/_/\\\\\\\\_/'`
echo $ch
```

when executed in a terminal or via `source` give an output

```
b\\_d
```

When ran as a scipt

```
sh script.sh
```

where the script contents are:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                   
ch=`echo "b_d" | sed 's/_/\\\\\\\\_/'`
echo $ch
```

the output is

```
b\_d
```

The output from the terminal is the preferred one. What is the solution for using the shell script? Also accepted as answers are ideas how to modify

```
ch=`echo "b_d" | sed 's/_/\\\\\\\\_/'`
```

for `sh`.

I use the bash shell:

```
echo $0
bash
```

Comment: What bash version do you use? I cannot repeat your problem.

Comment: [`sh` is not `bash`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Scripts). Also, if you run `$SHELL foo.sh` the shebang line is *ignored*. Please show us **exactly** what you are running.

Comment: @I0b0, I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sh` differs from `bash` and behaves different.

I guess that `sh` is really `dash`.

BTW: there is different behavior with this command if you check different shells.

`bosh`, `dash`, `mksh`, `zsh` as well as `ksh` on Solaris print one backslash

`bash` and `ksh` on Linux print two backslashes.

From looking at the $shell -x output, I believe that one backslash is the correct output.

I have no idea why `ksh` behaves this way on Linux. It could be that it tries to mimic `bash` behavior.

For `bash` the behavior can be explained: bash has a non-POSIX `echo` that does not interpret backshlashes as required by POSIX.

POSIX permits the behavior of `bash` only on small embedded systems and POSIX otherwise requires the so called `XSI` extensions to be implemented. With `echo`, this requires to fully follow the behavior of `echo` as impleented in 1982 by AT&T for SYSv.

An important note:

If you have a script that starts with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and that is executable (`x` bit set by`chmod`), and if you call

sh myscript

this script is still run by `/bin/sh` which is typically `dash` on Linux. So be careful on how you run your code.

There is a way to avoid your problem. Change your script to use:

```
ch=`echo "b_d" | sed 's/_/\\\\\\\\_/'`
printf '%s\n' $ch
```

This way, you avoid the problems with `echo` that have been introduced in 1989 with `bash`. `printf` does still not solve all problems since there are many buggy implementations, but the usual problems that arise from backslashes in the arguments are not affected by `printf`.

Comment: Could you please highlight in your answer to replace `sh` by `bash` in `sh script.sh`, as it solved my problem.

Comment: [_"If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined."_](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/echo.html)...

Comment: This is a missinterpretation of the POSIX standard. POSIX requires full `XSI` compliance for shells that are used on non-embedded systems. Note that my answer is verified by an related answer from Geoff Clare, the author of the POSIX certification test suite.

Comment: I think you need to add @ilkkachu to your comment.

Comment: @schily, can you add a link to that answer?

Comment: @ilkkachu That was in a POSIX teleconference call, there is no related text. BTW: as a result, I decided to include support for the useless `fc` command in `bosh` since I like `bosh` to be POSIX compliant. Geoff told me that there is no support to remove the `fc` command from the`XSI` list.

Comment: A more comprehensive explanation can be found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/5132 .

Comment: In a writing of that length, it would be nice if the order of the first part of the description did match historical order and if itmentioned that the escape secuence `\c` has been introduced in the mid 1970s with `troff` already. Also mentioning UNIX V8 would need to explain it's position in the timeline as it is not the successor of UNIX V7.